# SNMP Library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, snmp

Are there any open source libraries for doing SNMP GET/SETs using the Objective C/Cocoa Touch (for IPhone)?

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no SNMP implementations in Objective-C (that i an aware of). There are in C & C++.

I've had success at using [snmp++v2.8a](http://www.agentpp.com/snmp_ppv2_8/download_snmp_ppv2/download_snmp_ppv2.html). Just drop the `.h` and .`cpp` files required for the static libsnmp++.a into your x-code iphone project. And make the necessary tweaks for it to build. I had to add: `"-D_XPG4_EXTENDED -DGCC -DLINUX"` to Project Settings 'Other C++ Flags', and make some changes to the files. Then any file you are using the c++ objects from, rename from .m to .mm, to tell X-Code the file contains a mixture of objective-C and c++.

Comment: Andrew - Can you post a sample project somewhere? It would be of huge help to he iPhone dev community.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the C/C++ package called **[Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org)** ***(has nothing to do with .NET)*** is the best implementation of an SNMP library for both the manager (client) and the agent (server) sides. I've looked at a lot of them and used a lot of them, and Net-SNMP is the best of the lot. Open source.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some time working on building one of these for a project.

there's none for obj-c, or at least there weren't when I was looking last summer. there's a bunch of open source ones in c and c# that are a good starting spot for a port (or re-implementation).

Comment: +1 I think if you were to make your library available (whether open source or not), you'd be providing a valuable contribution to the community.

Comment: I honestly didn't see anybody who is even remotely interested in it :)

I'll post it whenever I get my new laptop and actually start doing useful things with myself again (buy applecare, kiddies. you never know when it'll work out in your favor)

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of one, and the only thing I'm finding on Google is "[IP*Works!](http://www.nsoftware.com/portal/macos/)", but it seems to be a Mac framework (and might not work on iPhone if it's not compiled as a .a file).

Your best bet may be to roll your own.  http://cocoabuilder.com has a couple emails in its archives about people asking for SNMP libraries, but no answers were ever received.